What does "Wild horses can puff and blow their snivelling hearts out" mean?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:

“Connie’s not coming back, George,” she called as she hobbled ahead of him. “Wild horses can puff and blow their snivelling hearts out, the old fool has hung up her boots for good.”

Does that have the similar meaning as the idiom "wild horses couldn't drag me away"?

Yes, it means that no matter how hard they try, snorting and puffing with effort, even wild horses would not succeed in getting Connie to return.
